# Bitmap.Config differences with/without alpha channel on a canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am drawing some Bitmaps to a canvas.  Some (most) of these bitmaps utilize the alpha channel, and transparency/translucency is critical for the image to look correct.  This is necessary due to some image manipulation I perform throughout the `Activity`.

Eventually the user is finished with their task and I take the canvas and save it to a PNG via use of this method:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

At this point I no longer make any modifications to the canvas/image but I do display the image to a `Canvas` in another `Activity`.  I want it to look ***exactly*** the same as in the previous `Activity`, so does it matter if I use `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` instead or will I lose information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will definitely lose information if you use Bitmap.Config.RGB_565. It may not be discernible on a phone display, but you're going from 24 bits of color information (not counting alpha) to 16 bits of color information when you go from RGB_8888 to RGB_565. Instead of 256 distinct red, green, and blue values in RGB_8888, there are only 64 distinct green values and 32 distinct red and blue values in RGB_565. This may cause banding or other sorts of quantization artifacts in your RGB_565 image.

Comment: Romain Guy gives a great explaination of all of this. 565 will give you less overall shades and I believe is Opaque. http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/

Comment: That blog is incredibly useful.  Thanks folks.